# media queries for phone

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries

i am trying to use media queries to have a style for screens larger than 768px and another one for smaller than 768px
when i resize the window the changes are happening but when i'm opening the website with phone or with the phone view in the Chrome inspector it doesnt work as I expect..
thanks !

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    body {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    #cont {
        background-color: aqua;
        width: 80vw;
    }

    #header {
        height: 30vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    #tophead {
        background-color: blueviolet;
        height: 5vh;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }

    #lefttophead {
        height: 80%;
        width: 40%;
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    #righttophead {
        height: 80%;
        width: 20%;
        background-color: orange;
    }

    #lowhead {
        height: 10vh;
        background-color: gold;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    #navbar {
        height: 80%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: hotpink;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }

    #onglets {
        width: 70%;
        height: 80%;
        background-color: cadetblue;
    }

    #searchbar {
        width: 20%;
        height: 80%;
        background-color: skyblue;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of *"doesnt work as I expect"*, what do you expect? looking your code, for devices with less than 768px wide, it should have the background "lightblue"

Comment: Show a proper [mre]. We can’t tell if you messed things up in your HTML (like not specifying a proper `viewport` meta tag to begin with), if you just show us some CSS.

Comment: thanks for your answer i searched on internet for the view port and fixed my mistake